# Verification error on unsafe c# return type using Peverify and ILVerify

Tags: c#, cil, peverify

I have run into this issue when verifying some code containing an unsafe method that returns a pointer.

The example can be expressed as this:

```
public class A
{
    public static unsafe int* GetAnswer()
    {
        int fakeValue = 42;
        return &(fakeValue);
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        int i = 0;
        unsafe { i = *A.GetAnswer(); }
        System.Console.WriteLine(i);
    }
}
```

I am using two separate verification tools, namely ILVerify and Peverify.

**Steps to reproduce:**

1. compile example code using `csc example.cs /t:library /unsafe`
2. verify `peverify example.dll`
3. verify `ILVerify.exe -r C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\mscorlib.dll example.dll`

Both 2. and 3. will result in the error message below:

> [IL]: Error: [C:\src\test\example.dll : A::GetAnswer()][offset 0x00000006][found address of Int32] Expected numeric type on the stack.
>
> [IL]: Error: [C:\src\test\example.dll : A::Main()][offset 0x00000009][found Native Int] Expected ByRef on the stack.
> 2 Error(s) Verifying C:\src\test\example.dll

The mystery is that everything compiles and runs as expected, it will not verify. Does anyone have some insight knowledge about why this is the case?

Comment: We need to see the code that is generating the IL with cecil to diagnose why it is generating unverifiable IL.

Comment: Not necessarily. This error is produced by the steps as marked in my question.

Comment: I see. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: That `unsafe` code is actively wrong, btw; it *really really* shouldn't return an address to an exiting stack-frame; "and runs as expected" - you shouldn't expect anything - it has undefined behavior

Comment: Even doing something like `fixed(int* ptr = &fakeValue) { return ptr; }` will give the same error.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_pointer

Comment: @miniwolf that "even doing something like" has the same problem; but *fundamentally* : unsafe code is unverifiable; you *will* have verification failures...

Comment: @MarcGravell so there is no way to resolve this error?

Comment: @miniwolf which error are you trying to resolve? your example code is fundamentally wrong, so first we need to understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: I am trying to return a pointer to a field inside the class A.

Comment: @miniwolf the moment you're talking about pointers: your code is unverifiable. Simple as. If you have a *specific example* of that, it would help (there is no field on `A` in your code) - and one very important thing is the placement of `fixed`. For example, this is **absolutely wrong** (although it compiles and "seems" to work): `int* GetPtr(A obj) { fixed(int* i = &obj.X) { return i; } }`. Frankly, you'd be much better off dealing in managed pointers (`ref int`) *if at all*. So: what are you trying to do? what is it that needs this pointer? You might be trying to solve the wrong thing...

Comment: @MarcGravell what I am trying to do is create a wrapper around `System.IO.UnmanagedMemoryStream` so that I can mock the calls into this class. The function `unsafe byte* PositionPointer { get; set; }` should be called through the wrapper that I am creating. So my version of `UnmanagedMemoryStream::PositionPointer` will call the real mscorlib version and return a "mocked" version of the result.

Comment: @miniwolf OK, but that code is going to be unverifiable; PEVerify *will not like it*. Whether it *works or not* is a separate issue, and will all depend on you pinning the object correctly.

Comment: I see. Thank you for the help and explaining the problem that is going on.

Answer (score 7):

Fundamentally: unsafe code is unverifiable. The exact messages you get back will often be vague and confusing, but then again: so is unsafe code (badum tsh)!

Worse: the code in the question is actively broken - there is no defined behaviour for what happens when you access a pointer from a stack-frame that has exited. In this case you'll usually get away with it and see the last values, but: it isn't defined.

If you want verifiable code, you're going to need to switch to `ref return`; for example:

```
static ref int GetAnswer(int[] arr)
{
    return ref arr[0];
}

static void Main()
{
    int i = 0;
    int[] j = new int[] { 42 };
    i = A.GetAnswer(j);
    System.Console.WriteLine(i);
}
```

This uses no unsafe code. `GetAnswer` returns a *reference* to the first element in the array (**not** the *value* of the first element) - as a *managed* pointer (`ref T` is a managed pointer; `T*` is an unmanaged pointer). Assigning `i = {someRef}` (rather than `i = ref {someRef}`) *deferences* the managed pointer, exactly like `i = *{somePtr}` does for an unmanaged pointer.

This verifies cleanly:

```
Microsoft (R) .NET Framework PE Verifier.  Version  4.0.30319.0
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

All Classes and Methods in ConsoleApp35.exe Verified.
```